UK visa expiring in 2 months and 25 days, can I get a Schengen visa?
I hold an UK PSW visa, my visa is expiring in 2 months and 24 days. If I apply to a Schengen visa, is it possible to get it because in the regulation of Schengen visa mentioned to apply 3 months.

You can try, but without a good reason it may be difficult: as I read, soon you have not work and you where not resident in your country since many years, and you do not have a resident permit on other countries. For me, more than the missing 5 days, it is about not having (almost in this question) strong application.

When would the trip take place? What are you planning to do after the end of your UK visa? Are you planning to stop in the Schengen area on the way back to your future country of residence or go back to the UK? As Giacomo explained, your current situation might be an issue regardless but above all you need a convincing plan. You definitely shouldn't get a multi-year multiple entry visa that would allow you to visit after you leave the UK but you might still get a short one.
